# addheader option

Tags: matlab, dll

I am using the function Loadllibrary, which has an "addheader" option went I use this option I get the following error :

> ??? Undefined function or method 'addheader' for input arguments of
>   type 'char'.

And here is the way I write the command :

```
loadlibrary EnobioAPI.dll Enobio.h addheader EnobioAPI_global
```

So I think that I should download this function because when I use the help to look for this function, I got a message that this function is not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably put `addheader` option to a new line. In this case MATLAB consider it as a new command.

If you need to split a command to several lines use `...` at the end of a line.